# Port 443 is close in Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I am a beginner with Google cloud platform. I have an instance and a custom domain. I installed the certificates for SSL. I am using [SSL checker](https://decoder.link/sslchecker/) and it seems port 443 is closed. I am getting the following error:

> 443 port seems to be filtered, check your firewall/server
>   configuration.

Following is my configuration for port 443 on firewall:

```
{
 "allowed": [
{
  "IPProtocol": "tcp",
  "ports": [
    "443"
  ]
}
],
"creationTimestamp": "2017-06-27T21:28:24.833-07:00",
"description": "",
"direction": "INGRESS",
"id": "515010694775......",
"kind": "compute#firewall",
"name": "default-allow-https",
"network": "projects/.../global/networks/default",
 "priority": 1000,
"selfLink": "projects/.../global/firewalls/default-allow-https",
"sourceRanges": [
"0.0.0.0/0"
],
"targetTags": [
"https-server"
]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem and realized that Google blocked by default port 443.
To solve the problem, just enable SSL in apache using the command: **`$ sudo a2enmod ssl`**

Then reboot the system and you will be able to access it with https!

Answer (score 1):

The firewall rule applies to any VM which has the corresponding `targetTags`, in this case it's the `https-server`.
Go to console and edit the VM you want to configure. In the firewall section you will notice a checkbox stating "Allow HTTPS traffic", which adds the tag you need. For custom firewall rules with custom `targetTags` you can just type them in the "Network tags" box bellow.
Then scroll down and hit Save, you should be sorted.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I have a custom domain that pointed to following name servers :  
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com. and I setup the DNS cloud for my custom domain. I also installed SSL certificate in the cloud console. My instance is ubuntu 17. I realized that port 433 was close on the instance and I enabled that but still no luck.